# Display up to N images in a browser window with optimal alignment by keeping 16:9

Tags: css, reactjs, image

This is a question, I'm discussing now for hours with ChatGPT w/o getting a satisfying answer. It is rediculous, but what ChatGPT produces is just a waste of time.

I would like to achieve this (in preparation of a video group call system I'm developing):

I would like to display up to N (N = 1..M) images by using the available canvas size optimal. The aspect ratio should always be kept as 16:9. Regardless of the canvas resolution it should never be necessary to scroll horizontally or vertically.

I wouldn't care about the alignment. So it is pretty much of no interest, if the images are stacked horizontally or vertically. I just don't want to scroll to see them all and they should keep 16:9.

The best I could get from ChatGPT was this:

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const images = [
  "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080",
  "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080",
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(16rem, 1fr))",
    gridGap: "1rem",
  },
  img: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    objectFit: "cover",
  },
}));

const Gallery = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <img src={image} alt={`Image ${index}`} className={classes.img} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

but it is not even close to meet my demands. Any CSS/React crack here having a better idea?

Comment: This isn’t so much a coding problem as a packing problem. Have you researched that?

Comment: Yes, to no avail.

Comment: Looks like a linear optimization task: Given a number of images to display and a given width/height: What would be the best alignment to display all and keep 16:9 in the given situation? Horizontal alignment or vertical alignment? Thanks for the trigger

Comment: Maybe like so (example for 2 images): Given the current w/h would be 1200:600. I could align both images horizontally. I would need to use width 600 for one. Gives 600*9/16=337.5 as height per image. One image would cover 600*337.5 pixels. A vertical alignment would use 1200 for width and 675 for height, so 1200*675, which is larger. In this case a vertical stack would be preferable. Something like this. EDIT: No, doesn't work. 675 is larger than 600 ... So the total height needs to be taken into account too...

Comment: Anyway, sounds easy. Thanks. Will accept as answer